# How to fix pixelated image in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, networkimageview

I want to create a rounded image widget, but it ends up pixelated.

With `Image.network(url)`, I get the following:

[image: Pixelated image]

while the original looks like this:

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
class RoundedImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String URL;
  final double size;
  final bool dynamicallySized;
  final double borderRadius;
  final bool onlyTopBorderRadius;

  const RoundedImage({
    @required this.size,
    @required this.url,
    this.dynamicallySized = false,
    this.borderRadius = 8.0,
    this.onlyTopBorderRadius = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final newSize = dynamicallySized ? PaddingUtils.getPadding(context, padding: size) : size;
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius:
          onlyTopBorderRadius ? BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(borderRadius)) : BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: url,
        height: newSize,
        width: newSize,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add this property to **CachedNetworkImage**

```
filterQuality: FilterQuality.high
```

Comment: Actually, it seems that when scaling down the image, `FilterQuality.medium` should produce better results. See this comment https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79645#issuecomment-819920763

Comment: for me neither are working